# jQuery: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Tags: jquery, runtime-error

In the script below, when I run it in the console, upon keyup in one of the customFields inputs, its returning an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Anyone see what's wrong?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

        jQuery("#customfield_21070").attr('style', 'width:60px');

        var customfields = '#customfield_11070,#customfield_11071,#customfield_20071,#customfield_20072,#customfield_20073,#customfield_20074';

           jQuery(customfields).keyup(function () {
                calculateSum.call(this);
            });


        function calculateSum(param) {
            var sum = 0;

            if (!isNaN(param.value) && param.value.length != 0 && param.id !== "customfield_21070") {
                sum += parseFloat(param.value);
            }

            jQuery("#customfield_21070").val(sum.toFixed(2));
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`calculateSum(this)` instead of `calculateSum.call(this)`

---

Explanation

The first parameter of `.call()` is not actually passing a parameter to the function you are actually calling. It is defining what the keyword `this` is **inside** the function.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call